# .bashrc or .profile for busybox on windows

Tags: bash, busybox, rc

I have enough experience with scripting on *nix servers, but busybox on Windows I enjoy first.
I installed busybox  using [`scoop`](https://scoop.sh/).
When I run:

```
ash
echo $HOME
```

I got ->

```
C:/Users/RO  # OK, this is dir of my windows profile
```

I thought I could put it in that directory something like `.profile` or `.bashrc`.
I tried it, but after restarting ash none of the contents of these files (eg. PATH, alias ...) was not set.
Is it possible to set some environment for busybox in these files?

Answer (score 5):

ash will execute a RC file that is specified in the `ENV` variable. If you created a file called `.ashrc` in your home directory, and executed ash with the `ENV` file set accordingly, it should work:

```
ENV=.ashrc ash
```

I'm unfamiliar with scoop/powershell, so I'm not 100% certain how you would accomplish setting the environment file from the Windows side.